# How to properly encrypt a file AES-CBC?

Tags: c, encryption, aes

When encrypting a file using AES_cbc_encrypt.

Do I need to while loop each AES_BLOCK_SIZE in the file and encrypt those in a buffer and write that in a new file? Something like that :

```
while (fread(buffer, 1, AES_BLOCK_SIZE, file) == AES_BLOCK_SIZE) {
    AES_cbc_encrypt(buffer, outputBuffer, AES_BLOCK_SIZE, &aeskeyEnc, iv_dec, AES_ENCRYPT);
}
```

Or even better can I read a block, encrypt it in-place on that file without creating a new file and iterate to the next block.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. In case of CBC you might want to store the IV somewhere if you plan on reusing the key. If push comes to shove you can store the IV at the end of the file instead of at the front. You may also memory map the file and perform encryption on the generated map.

You need to keep the last ciphertext as IV for the next ciphertext encryption. Encrypting more blocks at a time will likely give you performance benefits - there is often a performance penalty with regards to I/O and the setting of the IV if you encrypt block-by-block.

If you use CTR mode encryption you can even parallelize the encryption and jump to specific offsets in the file. Note that the I/O might be the bottleneck; parallelizing the encryption may not give much benefit in that case.